# Azure WebApp unable to connect to Storage Account and restarts every 5min when VNet is enabled

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

I have a new, simple Spring Boot application with a single REST endpoint that wants to store data in Azure Table Storage. When talking to the storage account from my dev machine, running the Spring Boot app in my IDE, everything works, the storage account connection string is used for auth.
(This dev machine is also running in a VM, hosted in Azure.)

However, when the app is deployed to the Web App, I have multiple issues:

- The storage account can not be reached, the deployed webapp service receives either a `com.azure.data.tables.models.TableServiceException` with 403 "This request is not authorized to perform this operation" if I use USer Managed Identitiy, OR `java.net.UnknownHostException` when trying to use the same connection string as from the IDE.
- Whenever VNet integration is turned on for the Web App:

  - The app seems to restart every 5 minutes
  - Manual deployment methods with AZ CLI or the maven plugin are timing out

**Some properties of the azure infra:**

- Azure Web App

  - Java 11 runtime
  - Linux OS for the App Service Plan
  - Always On turned on
  - ARR affinity: off
  - Health check disabled
- VirtualNet

  - Configured on both the Web App and Storage Account ends in the networking
- UAMI

  - assigned to the Web App
  - has Storage Table Data Contibutor role assigned to it for the storage account in question

I was unable to dig for useful error logs, that would hint for the root causes. In the App Service Diagnostics (Diagnose and Solve Problems blade) I did find this weird event type under "Web App restarted" diagnostic: ***NetmanMarkedUnhealthy***, which literally yields 0 google results.

Used dependencies:

- com.azure:azure-identity:1:4.3
- com.azure:azure-data-tables:12.3.11

Any idea what could cause these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **NetmanMarkedUnhealthy** could be what's causing your web app to restart every 5 minutes. This error, *Network Manager for Linux Unhealthy* event is related to health of the network interface as monitored by the Network Manager (netman) service.

Assuming you have service endpoints enabled, this issue will require further investigation in order to mitigate. Please send us an email to AzCommunity[at]microsoft[dot]com *ATTN: Ryan* enclosed with a link to this post, your app service name, and subscription id.

---

**EDIT 2023 June 13:** Try scaling you app service plan up/down to see if that mitigates the *NetmanMarkedUnhealthy* message you're getting.

Comment: Sadly I can not send you the email I think, the company where I work at I am pretty sure has some complicated support policy I would need to follow.  Thanks for the answer nonetheless, what worked this week by the way is creating a web app under a completetly new app service plan. It seemed to resolve both issues, now I am able to connect to the storage account via connection string as well. So yeah, seems like the app service plan itself has some network issues.